# Многоязычность на многостраничном сайте с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html, multilanguage

Всем привет. Решил немного попрактиковаться с php на своем старом учебном сайте. Там есть 7 отдельных страниц, на которые можно попасть через ссылки в меню навигации.
Решил сделать многоязычность. Eсть конфиг который определяет язык в браузере у пользователя и соответствоенно выдает перевод на нужном языке. Подсмотрел его в одном видосе. Он нормальный?

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
        if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
        else if ($_GET['lang'] == "ru")
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "ru";
  }
  require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
?>
```

Ну и соотвественно файл с массивом перевода.

Так же хотелось что бы на сайте язык выдавался не только автоматически, а и по кнопкам. Но как это реализовать не придумал. Еще нюанс в том, что `Header` и `Footer` в отдельных файлах и на каждую страницу подгружаются через `require`.

Отрывок header'a:

```
<div class="langgen">
         <a class="first_strip_1" href="index.php?lang=en" hreflang="en"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a>
         <a class="first_strip_1" href="index.php?lang=ru" hreflang="ru"><img class="lang" src="images/langru.png"></a>
      </div>
...
  <ul class="parent">
              <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link ourprj" href="Our Projects.php?lang=???"><?php echo $lang['our_proj'] ?></a></li>
              <li class="linav"><a id="btn" class="nav__link arr"><?php echo $lang['design'] ?><i class="arrow"></i></a>
                  <ul class="child">
                      <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link_child" href="Interior.php?lang=???"><?php echo $lang['Interior'] ?></a></li>
                      <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link_child" href="Exterier.php?lang=???"><?php echo $lang['exterier'] ?></a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link" href="Quiality.php?lang=???"></a></li>
              <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link" href="Contacts.php?lang=???"></a></li>
              <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link" href="About Us.php?lang=???"></a></li>
            </ul>
```

И вот на что я наткнулся, с самим авто определением языка и выдачи его пользователю проблем нет. И если переключаться между вкладками выбранный язык остается `href="About Us.php?lang=<?php echo $_SESSION['lang'} ?>` И ,например, пользователю выдастся `About Us.php?lang=ru` и если он будет переключаться между вкладками, то `ru` останется.
Но как реализовать переключатель языка.Ведь сессия с текущим языком браузера будет перебивать выбранный вручную язык. И какую ссылку давать на иконку (кнопку) перевода? Не очень красиво будет выглядеть если пользователя после перевода языка будет перекидывать на главную страницу. Можно ли задать как то динамическую ссылку, что бы php смотрел на какой странице пользователь и ей выдавал  `Текущая страница.php?lang=ru / Текущая страница.php?lang=en`.

Sorry если банальный вопрос, посмотрел несколько примеров везде был только один файл index, а на многостраничных реализацию никто не показывал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из всех ссылок нужно бы убрать это `?lang=???` и сделать две (ну, или сколько там языков) подобные:

```php
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url .= (strpos($url, '?') === false ? '?' : '&');
$url_ru = $url . 'lang=ru';
$url_en = $url . 'lang=en';
?>

<a href="<?=$url_ru?>">ru</a>
<a href="<?=$url_en?>">en</a>
```

Почему выбранный вручную будет перебивать сессию? Вы же, проверяя GET, сессию перезаписываете...

Comment: Да, действительно, работает)Спасибо!) Только какой то баг. Если на одной странице переключать языки то url сходи с ума, накладываясь друг на друга.
http:/mywebsite.ru/Contacts.php?lang=en&lang=ru&lang=en&lang=ru
Конечно это не критично, но можно как то пофиксить?

Comment: Хотел сначала писать про то, чтобы сделать форму, но стало лень, а об этом не подумал. По идее, я бы  использовал post запрос лучше. то есть сделать форму, в ней две кнопки и принимать не GET, а POST данные. чтобы не морочиться с url вообще.

Comment: Поискал в инете как можно заменить строку, а не добавить и вообщем нашел такую возможность через "str_replace". Я честно не до конца понял как она работает т.к. с php работаю пару дней, но она работает))) Она не добавляет новый lang, а заменяет.Код получился такой: 
`<?php         
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];       
$url = str_replace('', '', ''); 
?> 
<a href="<?=$url . '?lang=en'?>"><img class="lang" src="images/langen.png"></a> <a href="<?=$url . '?lang=ru'?>"><img class="lang" src="images/langrus.png"></a>`

Смущает только то что параметры `str_replace` пустые)))